# Two gnome-sessions

Tags: gnome, gdm, tty, ibus, gnome-session

I have two process gnome-session-binary running on my computer. One is running with my user and one is running with the gnome display manager user, they are running in different tty's.

[my user running gnome-session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZCqz.png)

[gdm running gnome session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9YlD.png)

They are also both running ibus-x11 --kill-daemon:

[both users running ibus-x11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUaLu.png)

Is this the correct behavior of gnome? And if it is, why?

Comment: I have the same problem, and it's very annoying as the gdm-owned /usr/bin/gnome-shell never stops consumer resident RAM